# Why is dynamically allocated memory in a shared memory reset to the initial value it was initialised to

Tags: c, shared-memory

I have the following code that initializes a shared memory, with the starting values:

```c
void initializeSharedMemory(SharedMemoryPtr sharedMemoryPtr, int size) {
    sharedMemoryPtr->bestSolutionDistance = 1e9; 
    sharedMemoryPtr->BestSolutionFoundByProcess = -1; 
    sharedMemoryPtr->BestSolutionFoundInIterations = -1;
    sharedMemoryPtr->solutionVector = createVector(size);
    sharedMemoryPtr->dataTest  = calloc(size,sizeof (int));
    initializeVector(sharedMemoryPtr->solutionVector, sharedMemoryPtr->dataTest);
}
```

i have a sharedMemory struct:

```c
typedef struct{
    int bestSolutionDistance;
    int BestSolutionFoundByProcess;
    int BestSolutionFoundInIterations;
    VectorPtr solutionVector;
} SharedMemory;
```

And a typedef for `SharedMemoryPtr`

```c
typedef SharedMemory *SharedMemoryPtr;
```

on my main.c i create the shared memory, map it and initialize it:

```c
size_t sharedMemorySize = sizeof(SharedMemory);
int shm_fd = createOrOpenSharedMemory(SHM_NAME, sharedMemorySize);
if (shm_fd == -1){
    fprintf(stderr,"Error Opening shared memory!\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

sharedMemoryAllocatedPtr = mapSharedMemory(shm_fd,sharedMemorySize);
if (sharedMemoryAllocatedPtr == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr,"Error Mapping shared memory!\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

initializeSharedMemory(sharedMemoryAllocatedPtr,distanceMatrix->size);
```

problem is on my child processes i can update the shared memory to update the best solution found, it updates without a problem, but when i wanna print the final state of the shared memory after all processes exit, the values go back to the initial values defined in`initializeSharedMemory`:

```
=========================Arguments=======================================
Problem file: ex5.txt , numProcesses: 1, maxIterations: 1000000000, maxDuration: 5s
Distance Matrix { 
0 23 10 4 1 
23 0 9 5 4 
10 9 0 8 2 
4 5 8 0 11 
1 4 2 11 0 
}
=========================================================================
Vector was this before updating:Vector { 0 0 0 0 0 }
Vector is now this after:Vector { 3 4 2 1 0 }
Vector was this before updating:Vector { 3 4 2 1 0 }
Vector is now this after:Vector { 1 0 3 2 4 }
Vector was this before updating:Vector { 1 0 3 2 4 }
Vector is now this after:Vector { 0 4 2 1 3 }
==========================Done===========================================
Best Solution:
Vector { 0 0 0 0 0 }
Found at iteration: 1290817 by PID: 5295
Distance: 21
=========================================================================
```

Comment: I gave an answer for the tiny amount I can say, with certainty, is wrong here. But without a [MCVE] there are *so* many things that could be wrong. You need to provide a [MCVE], and specify your OS (with all your wrapper functions, there's no way for us to tell) to get complete answers.

Comment: As a side-note: `typedef`s for "pointer to this other type" are a crutch. They save you from mistakes like `SomeType* a, b;` (where `a` is a pointer to `SomeType`, but `b` is an actual `SomeType`, despite looking like you declared both as a pointer to the novice; it should be `SomeType *a, *b;`, with the `*` attached to the name because it really is attached to the name, not the type, regardless of spacing), but they also make it harder for you to understand pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `struct` is allocated in shared memory, but `sharedMemoryPtr->dataTest` (and possibly `sharedMemoryPtr->solutionVector`, but you failed to provide the definition of `createVector`, so who knows?) is allocated on the local process heap via `calloc`; it's not in shared memory. The parent process, not having done anything since creating it zeroed, only sees it as zeroes after, because changes the other processes make to their local heap are local to those processes.

Odds are, the code is "working", rather than crashing, because you're on an OS, and using APIs, to perform `fork`-based parallelism, so the `calloc`-ed memory remains at the same address in the child processes; with anything other than `fork`-based parallelism, ASLR would likely relocate the heap and the attempt to dereference an address `calloc`-ed in the parent process from any child process would die trying to read unallocated memory. With `fork`, it just performs a copy-on-write in the child process, so the child can use the memory just fine, but the changes are purely local to the child, with the parent retaining its pristine zeroed memory.

Comment: I've fixed it by allocating new shared memory for the vector itself, that way its not heap memory, therefore all processes will write to the same memory. Thanks for your help!